# Limit of x/(1+x^2) as x becomes small

Tags: limits

It seems to be clear that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{1+x^2}=0
\end{equation}
with $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ shown below. Clearly, $f(x)=0$ from both $x=0^+$ and $x=0^-$. The solution above could also be confirmed using online calculators (e.g. WolframAlpha).

[image]

However, $x^2$ goes to 0 faster than $x$, so it could be said that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\epsilon}\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\epsilon
\end{equation}

with $\epsilon$ small. For instance, take a few small values:

| $\epsilon$ | $f(\epsilon)$ |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.0990099 |
| 0.01 | 0.009999 |
| 0.001 | 0.000999999 |
| $10^{-6}$ | $10^{-6}/(1+10^{-12})\approx 10^{-6}$ |

So it seems that the limit goes to $\epsilon$ (and hence $x$ for the original limit above), rather than $0$. What is the correct way of expressing this mathematically?

Is there a formal way to prove this, or to better explain what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write the Newton's expansion of the function:
$$\frac {x}{1+x^2}=x(1+x^2)^{-1}=x(1-x^2+x^4-x^6+...)$$
This is valid if $|x|<1$.
Now, as ${x\to 0}$, higher powers get neglected, and the function is well-approximated by simply $f(x)=x$. But ${x\to 0}$ itself, hence limit value would be $0$.